# Proving that $a_{n+1}=a^{2}_{n}+\frac{1}{4}$ diverges to $+\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

This problem looks very interesting to me. It is a requirement to show that if

> $$a_{n+1}=a_{n}^{2}+\dfrac{1}{4},\;n=1,2,3,\cdots\;\;\text{and}\;\;a_1=a,\;\;\text{then}$$
>
> Case 1. $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n=\dfrac{1}{2}\;\;\text{if}\;\;0<a\leq \dfrac{1}{2}.$$
>
> Case 2. $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n=\infty\;\;\text{if}\;\;a>\dfrac{1}{2}.$$
>
> Proof of Case 1.
>
> To prove 1, we need to show two things (i) monotonicity (ii) boundedness
>
> (i) Monotonicity:
>
> $$a_{n+1}-a_{n}=a_{n}^{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}-a_{n}=\left(a_{n}-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{2}\geq 0,$$
> $$\implies a_{n}\leq a_{n+1}\;\;\forall\;\; n\geq 1.$$
> Hence, $\{a_{n}\}$ is a monotone increasing sequence.
>
> (ii) Boundedness:
>
> Claim. $a_{n}\leq \dfrac{1}{2}\;\;\forall\;\; n\geq 1$
>
> Proof of claim. The statement is true when $n=1$, since
>
> $$a_{2}=a_{1}^{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}=a^{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}\leq \dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{4}=\dfrac{1}{2}.$$
>
> Assume it is true for $n=k$, that is
>
> $$ a_{k+1}=a_{k}^{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}\;\;\text{for some}\;\; k\in N$$
>
> Now, we prove it is true for $n=k+1$, i.e.,
>
> $$ a_{k+2}=a_{k+1}^{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}=\left(a_{k}^{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^2+\dfrac{1}{4}\leq \dfrac{1}{2}.$$
>
> Thus, by mathematical induction, it is true for all cases of $k\in N.$
>
> Since it is monotone increasing and bounded above, it converges. The limit is easy to find. Let
>
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n=x,$$ then
>
> $$x=x^{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}$$
> $$\implies x=\dfrac{1}{2} \;\;(\text{twice}).$$
> Thus, it is bounded by $1/2.$

Now, I have some issues with Case 2 but I'll give a useful definition.

> Definition. A sequence $\{a_n\}$ is said to diverge to $+\infty$ if for any $M\in R,\;\exists\; n_M\in N\;$ such that
> $$a_n> M\;\;\forall \;\;n\geq n_M.$$

My question is; how do I prove Case 2? If there are better ways of solving Case 1, I'll gladly welcome it. Corrections too, are welcome!

Comment: How can you say $(a_n-1/2)^2\le 0?$  A square is nonnegative.  Also, your induction proof is not technically correct.  The induction hypothesis is $a_{k+1}\le 1/2$

Comment: @ saulspatz: My mistake, I'll correct it!

Comment: If your sequence is increasing and bounded, then it will converge to its supremum. Also, good job on case 1, the proof looks very neat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint on approaching the problem directly: consider the quantity $b_n=a_n-\frac12$.  Then you should be able to rewrite your recurrence in terms of $b_n$ and then find a simple inequality on $b_{n+1}$ in terms of $b_n$. (In particular, this will be another proof that $b_n$ is an increasing sequence!) Finally, using the fact that $b_1=a-\frac12\gt 0$, show that $b_n$ is unbounded; that is, for each $M$ you can find an $n_M$ such that $b_{n_M}\gt M$ (and thus $b_n\gt M$ for all $n\geq n_M$, since $b_n$ is an increasing sequence).

(Note that you won't be able to show *uniform* divergence; your $n_M$ will depend on the particular $a$ you're given as a starting condition. This is inevitable, because in fact the series isn't uniformly divergent — for any sufficiently large $M$ and any $n'$, there's some $a$ such that it will take you more than $n'$ steps for the sequence to get greater than $M$.)

Comment: @ Steven Stadnicki, I can't wonder for long! That's the reason why you have 39k! You are distinct and very good! You answered it directly!

Comment: @ Steven Stadnicki, please can you help me write it more explicitly? I mean the way it should really appear! I am just starting with the divergence proofs. I believe you are well able to show the way out! Thanks!

Comment: Consider this: $b_1$ is a quantity greater than $0$. $b_n$ will always be at least $b_1$, so in particular $b_n^2\geq b_1^2$. But you know that the difference between $b_{n+1}$ and $b_n$ is this size. (You proved this in the initial analysis.) So what happens after $M/(b_1^2)$ steps?

Comment: Now, I see your point, Steven Stadnicki! It will diverge!

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that $a_n$ has a finite limit $l$, then we have : 
$$ \lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n+1} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n \text{ hence if } a_n \text{ converges we have : } l = l^2 + \frac{1}{4}$$

This equation has the only solution $l = \frac{1}{2}$, hence if $a_0 > \frac{1}{2}$, because $a_n$ is clearly strictly increasing, we are done. (ie. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = +\infty$).

Comment: Thank you Salutsalut1! Thanks for that observation!

Comment: @ Salutsalut1: That definition is what I am interested in using.

Comment: This only proves that if it converges, it converges to $1/2$.  You still have to prove converges when $a\le 1/2

Comment: It does prove that it converges when $0 < a_0 < \frac{1}{2}$ and that it diverges when $ a_0 > 1/2$

Comment: @ saulspatz: Please, can you edit your comment? I can't see clearly!

Comment: @ saulspatz: Please, can you show me how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: There are strictly increasing sequences that converge, so how you know for sure that it is unbounded?

Comment: I'm having issues understanding the proof of this part. Would anyone care to elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: Just realised it's the same argument that I employed. +1

Comment: @Shashi If it converges, it has to converge to $1/2$, but $a_n$ is increasing and : $a_0 > 1/2$, there's just nothing more to proove

Comment: @Salutsalut1 now I see it! +1

Answer (score 2):

You have already proved that if $(a_n)$ converges, then its limit is 1/2. You've also proved that $(a_n)$ is an increasing sequence. Now, since it is increasing and if $a_o =1/2$, then $1/2$ is a lower bound for the sequence and the sequence can never converge to it. This implies, that the sequence diverges to $+\infty$. It's positive because $(a_o)$ is positive and we have an increasing sequence.

Comment: Thank you A.Asad! I am still looking for a direct application of the definition I gave. You can help by employing that. It's imperative!